# Is there a console command to quit the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

In almost all FPS games where there's a console, there's a `quit` command that whisks you right out of the game without you having to answer a bunch of yes/no questions.

Does Skyrim's PC console have such a command?

Comment: Alt-F4 doesn't work?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it indeed doesn't.  I even made sure my G11 keyboard wasn't in game mode.  Either way, `qqq` console command does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the console command to immediately force quit the game is `qqq`